# How to get messages from Kafka Consumer one by one in java?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Apache Kafka API and trying to get only one message at a time. I'm only writing to one topic. I can send and receive messages by having a pop UI screen with a textbox. I input a string in the textbox and click "send." I can send as many messages as I want. Let's say I send 3 messages and my 3 messages were "hi," "lol," "bye." There is also a "receive" button. Right now, using the traditional code found in [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_kafka/apache_kafka_consumer_group_example.htm#:%7E:text=Kafka%20assigns%20the%20partitions%20of,were%20stored%20in%20the%20log.), I get all 3 messages (hi, lol, bye) at once printed on the console when I click on the receive button. However, I want only want one message to be printed at a time when I click "receive" on the UI. For example, the first time I hit the receive button, it would print "hi," the second time would be "lol," and the third time would be "bye." I am new to Kafka and am confused on how to do this. I tried removing both the loops from the code so it just has

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
System.out.printf(records.iterator().next().value());
```

If I just have those 2 lines of code, the first time I hit the receive button, it would print "hi" but the second time I press it,  get the message "attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing kafka." I'm getting errors when I set the max.poll.records = 1 too as I want all my messages *eventually* but just one of them needs to be logged to the console when the receive button is pressed. The next time, the next message in the topic not logged would be logged.

Hope that makes sense!
Appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
New code after including queues and also so we can alternate between sending and receiving messages & update the queue whenever there is a new message:

```
        if (payloadQueue.isEmpty()){
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
            if (records.isEmpty()) {
                log.info("No More Records to Add");
                consumer.close();
            }
            else {
                records.iterator().forEachRemaining(record -> {
                    log.info("RECORD: " + record);
                    payloadQueue.offer(record);
                });
                payload = payloadQueue.poll().value();
                log.info("Received event from KAFKA on subject {} with payload \"{}\"", subject, payload);
            }
        }
        else {
            payload = payloadQueue.poll().value();
            log.info("Received event from KAFKA on subject {} with payload \"{}\"", subject, payload);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka use batch get to improve performance, it's really not necessary to set max.poll.records=1.
What you want can be easily achieved with some workaround.

## solution

You can have a `Queue` to store the message, each time the receive button is pressed, you poll one message from the queue, if the queue is empty, you call `consumer.poll` to fill the queue.

## code

```
    private Queue<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> queue=new LinkedList<>();
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(properties);
    public void buttonPressed(){
        if (queue.isEmpty()){
            consumer.poll(100).iterator().forEachRemaining(record->queue.offer(record));
        }else {
            System.out.println(queue.poll());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this!!! The only thing I forgot to mention about the UI is: Let's say I sent 3 messages (hi, lol, bye) and click receive twice and get "hi" and "lol" back. I'd want to send another message "hello" even though I haven't logged all messages yet. The next two times I click the receive button, I'd get "bye" and "hello" back. I've edited my post above to show my new code for the buttonPressed() method. Is the code above the best way to do this? It looks messy. Plus, I've "consumer.close() in two places. It gives errors if I don't have "consumer.close()" in the first if. Why?

Comment: Basically, I'd want to update the queue dynamically whenever a new message is sent without touching the code for sendButton() method.

Comment: 1. you don't need to close the consumer in this method, the consumer only need to be closed when the application is closed.    

2. you don't have to call `consumer.poll` each time, you only have to call it when the queue is empty.   

3. If you want to update the queue without press the button, you'd have another thread to periodically poll message into the queue.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the heartbeat errors now. One last question (hopefully!): if the queue is empty and I poll but there are no more messages, I am again getting the group is rebalancing error. I understand why since the set was empty. How do I deal with that? I have a "records.isEmpty()" if statement but it still logs the "group is rebalancing error" before and after logging "no more records to add." I have the updated code in the post. Thanks again!

Comment: @techCells Did it throws exception? If it does, please give the  stack trace.

Comment: No, there isn't an exception. I just get the log message "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing" in a loop and somewhere in between that, it enters the "records.isEmpty()" if statement, prints "No More Records to Add" and then continues saying "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing" infinite amount of times unless I kill the application.

Comment: Do you know which line of code print this log message. It seems has nothing to do with your above code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is "ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(...);" 
as every other if-else block has a log statement and none of them are being called. Plus, I'm only getting the heartbeat message if there aren't any records to be returned

Comment: I finally got this message: Member consumer-kafka-consumer-group-1-645c24e8-05b6-43c4-a45a-dedbbdc0f105 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Queue as suggested by @haoyu, but manually commiting consumed offsets. Otherwise an application reset may lead to data loss (because the messages have been consumed from the topic, despite not being printed into the UI).

It is recommended to read the section "Manual Offset Control" and "Storing Offsets Outside Kafka" of [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html) javadoc.